# Does the 3D structure generated with MolView violate the wedge-dash rules of "above/below the plane"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, halides, software

I've been taught that in a wedge-dash diagram, the wedge represents a bond *above* the plane of the paper, and the dash represents a bond *below* the plane.

Accordingly, I expected the structure of this particular conformer of 1,2-dichloro-1,2-difluoroethane to have the fluorine groups in a *trans* orientation. I am aware that conformers can interconvert, but my question is about the wedge-dash representation of this particular conformer; the representation obviously cannot interconvert.

[image]

In other words, I was expecting the structure to have the following sawhorse projection:

[image]

But when I ran it through MolView, I got the following structure, in which both fluorine groups seem to be above the plane.

[image]

That is, the structure had the following sawhorse projection:

[image]

Am I missing something? Or is the 3D structure from MolView wrong? I am not referring to the *R*/*S* configurations here; my doubt is only in the wedge-dash representation.

Comment: I think you should check out how *conformers* work, particularly interconvert...

Comment: The molecule can rotate freely around the C-C axis. But I would interchange one $\ce{H}$ and one $\ce{F}$ atom on the left (lower) carbon atom on the picture.

Comment: @Mithoron I know that there an infinite number of possible conformers of this molecule, and that they interconvert. I wanted to know about this specific conformer, because my question is about the representation itself.

Comment: @andselisk My question is not about the R/S configurations, but the wedge-dash notation.

Comment: Get the stereochemistry right before dealing with conformation. follow the advice of @Maurice regarding H and F.

Comment: @Maurice Do you mean that the F atoms should be opposite to each other in the 3D diagram? Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: I cannot post anything as an answer, as the post has been closed. Now, yes, the $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{F}$ atoms must be interchanged in the 3D diagram, because in the original diagram, the two atoms $\ce{F}$ and the two atoms $\ce{Cl}$ are supposed to be trans.

Comment: What happens if you put the wide end of the dashed arrow on the alkyl chain? The way you drew it could have misled MolView.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I tried that and got this error: "Failed to load structure from sketcher Unknown stereocenter configuration: F, charge 0, 1 bonds (0 double)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MolView has issues with preserving stereochemistry when converting 2D to 3D](https://blog.molview.org/2016/10/10/issues-in-3d-resolving/). Do not expect accurate conversion of the drawn wedge-and-dash projection into the three-dimentional model because the structure is converted to the proprietary SMILES format first, and despite [SMILES having support for stereochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system#Stereochemistry), there is no uniform open standard.

MolView sends generated SMILES to third-party services such as [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) and [CID](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure), and numerous things may break (and they do) along the way, for example, since there is no hydrogen atoms in the SMILES generated within MolView if none explicit hydrogens were drawn, the stereochemistry interpreted by PubChem has nothing to do with the intended one because their API expects an isomeric SMILES string with explicit hydrogen atoms.

If you still want to use MolView to depict stereoisomers, use the search function with one of the following queries:

- [name with proper stereodescriptors](https://molview.org/?q=(1R,2S)-1,2-dichloro-1,2-difluoroethane): `(1R,2S)-1,2-dichloro-1,2-difluoroethane`

  [image: name with proper stereodescriptors]
- [isomeric SMILES containing explicit hydrogen atoms](https://molview.org/?q=F%5BC@@H%5D(Cl)%5BC@H%5D(F)Cl): `F[C@@H](Cl)[C@H](F)Cl`

  [image: isomeric SMILES containing explicit hydrogen atoms]

In your case you were getting wrong structure for (1*S*,2*S*)‐1,2‐dichloro‐1,2‐difluoroethane with SMILES string `F[C@@H](Cl)[C@@H](F)Cl`, which had nothing to do with your drawing, rather with interconversion process. Always check how the software operates and don't blindly rely on technology without understanding its limitations.